# Understanding continuations with std::future::then

Tags: c++, c++14

Can anybody explain with an example in C++ what is the difference between `async([](){x(); y();})` and `async([](){x();}).then([](){y();})` ? My understanding is that in the latter case each of `x`, `y` would possibly start in different threads immediately and would only block (in their respective thread) if a `get()` was invoked on the future passed as input.

Comment: `then`? What is that a member function of?

Comment: it will a member of std::future in the next standard, if I am not wrong

Comment: @Columbo: See [N3858](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3858.pdf).

Comment: sorry there is no 'z'. fixed. I used pseudo language to be short..I thought it was clear, isn't it?

Comment: OK, what's `+` supposed to mean?

Comment: OK: the thing was meant to be a short for std::async([](){x(); y();});

Comment: Why don't you write actual code, instead of fake code? Especially when you're asking about what that code does? *facepalm*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a `get()` can never block. This is by design in the relevant proposal, [N3558](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3558.pdf).

> ```
> #include <future>
> using namespace std;
> int main() {
>    future<int> f1 = async([]() { return 123; });
>
>    future<string> f2 = f1.then([](future<int> f) {
>         return f.get().to_string(); // here .get() won’t block
>    });
> }
> ```
>
> *[..]*
>
> Each continuation will not begin until the preceding has completed.

The benefit is that you can now *compose* several asynchronous operations in an expressive way. Could you just bundle all the code into a single lambda instead? Sure. But ew. Not re-usable and not particularly maintainable either.

Furthermore, there's some exception handling magic done for you. I suggest reading the proposal that defines what `std::future::then` will actually do, though I admit that there's not much in the way of a "Rationale" section in there: it seems to focus on the downsides of blocking your main thread waiting for a future to complete, and doesn't mention your stated alternative use case. Well, maybe that's the problem: this feature *isn't* very much designed to replace it. That's why you're struggling to find the functional differences.

> In asynchronous programming, it is very common for one asynchronous operation, on completion, to invoke a second operation and pass data to it. The current C++ standard does not allow one to register a continuation to a future. With .then, instead of waiting for the result, a continuation is “attached” to the asynchronous operation, which is invoked when the result is ready. Continuations registered using the .then function will help to avoid blocking waits or wasting threads on polling, greatly improving the responsiveness and scalability of an application.

Comment: @immibis: A function that performs "<logic A> <logic B>" does not make either of those distinct pieces of logic independently reusable, is my point. If those were two lambdas then you have maximum flexibility and can compose them however you please.

Comment: Here's the "non-reusable" single lambda: `[](){ x(); y(); }`. Is the entire lambda expression as reusable as the two separate lambdas would be? No. Does it matter in the slightest? No, because you can still reuse `x` and `y`.

Comment: @immibis: In this contrived example, sure, but I'm supposing a more general case where the lambda itself is more than just two further function calls.

Answer (score 7):

> ... what is the difference between `async([](){x(); y();})` and `async([](){x();}).then([](){y();})`?

Not much really - so why have it then?

In a single word *composability*. It allows us to construct abstractions based on modular functions (or pieces of functionality) in an asynchronous environment in a expressive manner given the problem domain.

That is not to say the one is right and the other wrong - it just means that those semantics (of `.then()`) is particularly meaningful when dealing with asynchronous operations.

The language of single threaded computations is something like "do this *and* do this *and* do this..." (before we carry on with other things), the language of asynchronous computation is "do this, and when it is done, *then* do this, and when it is done, *then* do this..." (while we carry on with other things).